# Using a Exception's instance in catch clause

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
public class ExceptionObject {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Exception exceptionObj = new Exception();
        int a=1, b=0; 

        try
        {
            int c=a/b;
        }
        catch(exceptionObj)
        {
            exceptionObj.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Why cant I use the "exceptionObj" which is an instance of the class Exception in catch clause.
Please advise, would be helpful.

Comment: Catch is an exception handler and exception that the handler can handle, must be the name of a class that inherits from the Throwable class. Here you are passing reference of class and a reference variable can point to any reference to same or sub class.

Comment: Because you have a syntax error. You have to provide the type as well as the name of the exception. T instance variable you have declared is completely pointless.

Comment: @HimanshuJain Your comment is at least partly incorrect, and you certainly have not identified the real problem here.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Can you please elaborate, that can help me to better understand and will be more than happy to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int a = 1, b = 0;

try {
 int c = a / b;
} catch (Exception exceptionObj) {
 exceptionObj.printStackTrace();
}
```